# Dynamic creation of SSRS Data driven subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, msbi

I am supposed to create about 150 subscriptions which will be SSRS Data driven.
As this can be a tedious task to create each subscription.I am seeking help if there is a way to run data driven subscriptions using a script? or query?. Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is doable for data driven subscriptions. I know that the question was different but if you may modify subscriptions to be standard, then it would be possible to create them by batch using [ReportingServicesTools](https://github.com/microsoft/ReportingServicesTools) with New-RsSubscription command (type `get-help New-RsSubscription -examples` in powershell)